# Swipe to Refresh Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I've combed through all the responses I see but I haven't been able to find a solution. I am new to Android Studio and to the world of Java. I am learning but need to ask for help.

I've created a very simple app using the WebView widget. The WebView widget is basically loading a site I've already fully built in PHP. I'm trying to add swipe to refresh to the app to give users the ability to have control similar to Facebook or other social media platforms. No matter what I try, I've been unable to nest my code correctly or create the correct references in my activity_main.xml file to get anything but a crash.

I've intentionally tried to strip my code of some sensitive identifying information. Package name is different in my actual file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:MyEmanuel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/Example"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My MainActivity.java looks like this:

```
package com.example.example;

   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.Window;
   import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
   import android.webkit.WebSettings;
   import android.webkit.WebView;
   import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Example);
        browser.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");

        /*load message while peek loads */
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Example);
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
                setTitle("Loading a fresh perspective...");
                setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

                // Return the app name after finish loading
                if (progress == 100)
                    setTitle("Peek Devotion");
            }
        });

        /*enables javascript with-in webview */
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView viewx, String urlx) {
                /* Check to see if URL is with-in My Emanuel, stay in app if so */
                if (Uri.parse(urlx).getHost().equals("www.google.com")) {
                    viewx.loadUrl(urlx);
                    return false;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlx));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        /* check to see if back button is pressed, if so return to last page */
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Example);
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        /*detects when window loses focus to refresh peek while closing .Resume to change */
        super.onPause();
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Example);
        webView.reload();
    }
}
```